# Select folder dialog WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I develop a WPF4 application and in my app I need to let the user select a folder where the application will store something (files, generated reports etc.).

My requirements:

- Ability to see the standard folder tree
- Ability to select a folder
- WPF look & feel, this dialog must look like part of a modern application designed for Windows Vista/7 and not Windows 2000 or even Win9x.

As I understand, until 2010 (.Net 4.0) there won't be a standard folder dialog, but maybe there are some changes in version 4.0?

Or the only thing I can do, is to use an old-school `WinForms` dialog? If it's the only way to do what I need, how can I make it looking closer to Vista/7 style and not Win9x?

Comment: Check out Sven Groot's fantastic [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) for both WinForms and WPF, which give you modern "Vista" style folder and file dialogs.

Comment: I'm using wxPython python module https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix

Comment: Here's a link to an updated [Ookii Dialogs for WPF](https://github.com/caioproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) targetting .NET 4.5 and [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf/)

Comment: See [This solution using Microsoft.Win32.OpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50263779/3226105)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FolderBrowserDialog` class from `System.Windows.Forms` is the recommended way to display a dialog that allows a user to select a folder.

Until recently, the appearance and behaviour of this dialog was not in keeping with the other file system dialogs, which is one of the reasons why people were reluctant to use it.

The good news is that `FolderBrowserDialog` [was "modernized" in NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/winforms#modernization-of-the-folderbrowserdialog), so is now a viable option for those writing either Windows Forms or WPF apps targeting that version or later.

> In .NET Core 3.0, Windows Forms users *[sic]* a newer COM-based control that was introduced in Windows Vista:
> [image: FolderBrowserDialog in NET Core 3.0]

To [reference `System.Windows.Forms` in a NET Core WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58844785), it is necessary to edit the project file and add the following line:

```xml
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

This can be placed directly after the existing `<UseWPF>` element.

Then it's just a case of using the dialog:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

using var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog
{
    Description = "Time to select a folder",
    UseDescriptionForTitle = true,
    SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
                    + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
    ShowNewFolderButton = true
};

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ...
}
```

`FolderBrowserDialog` has a `RootFolder` property that supposedly *"sets the root folder where the browsing starts from"* but whatever I set this to it didn't make any difference; `SelectedPath` seemed to be the better property to use for this purpose, however the trailing backslash is required.

Also, the `ShowNewFolderButton` property seems to be ignored as well, the button is always shown regardless.

Answer (score 117):

[Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/windows-presentation-foundation-4-5-cookbook/book) by Pavel Yosifovich on page 155 in the section on "Using the common dialog boxes" says:

> "What about folder selection (instead of files)? The WPF
> OpenFileDialog does not support that. One solution is to use Windows
> Forms' FolderBrowserDialog class. Another good solution is to use the
> Windows API Code Pack described shortly."

I downloaded the API Code Pack from <s>[Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)</s> [*Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665/109702), then added references to Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll and Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll to my WPF 4.5 project.

Example:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dlg.Title = "My Title";
dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
dlg.InitialDirectory = currentDirectory;

dlg.AddToMostRecentlyUsedList = false;
dlg.AllowNonFileSystemItems = false;
dlg.DefaultDirectory = currentDirectory;
dlg.EnsureFileExists = true;
dlg.EnsurePathExists = true;
dlg.EnsureReadOnly = false;
dlg.EnsureValidNames = true;
dlg.Multiselect = false;
dlg.ShowPlacesList = true;

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok) 
{
  var folder = dlg.FileName;
  // Do something with selected folder string
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe Microsoft didn't bother to include a FolderBrowserDialog by default in WPF...

Comment: The Windows API Code Packs are available via Nuget [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Shell/) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Core/). This worked well for me.

Comment: It works fine with me. Also I just write the commands below so the post has all information.
Install via Package Manager Console in VS

"Install-Package Windows7APICodePack-Core"

,           "Install-Package Windows7APICodePack-Shell"

Comment: I believe the link to this file is down.

Comment: I tried this but `CommonOpenFileDialog` was not recognised. (Yes I put the `using` in).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You should install package via nuget:
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Shell -Version 1.1.1

Comment: Thanks for coming back with some advice. I couldn't find the menu entry for the "package manager console" to type this in. So instead I went to the "manage nuget packages" area, found this package (by the same author) and installed it. I'm fairly certain it was installed, because the `using` worked fine. The answer at the bottom of this page worked for me first time without any fiddling with nuget packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547320/using-folderbrowserdialog-in-wpf-application/4547385#comment76194007_4547385

Comment: `CommonOpenFileDialog` is IDisposable. You should wrap your code inside a `using` directive.

Answer (score 21):

I wrote about it on my blog a long time ago, WPF's support for common file dialogs is really bad (or at least is was in 3.5 I didn't check in version 4), but it's easy to work around it.

You need to add the correct manifest to your application, that will give you a modern style message boxes and folder browser (`WinForms`, `FolderBrowserDialog`) but not WPF file open/save dialogs, this is described in those 3 posts (if you don't care about the explanation and only want the solution go directly to the 3rd):

- [Why am I Getting Old Style File Dialogs and Message Boxes with WPF](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2008/05/28/Why-am-I-Getting-Old-Style-File-Dialogs-and-Message.aspx)
- [Will Setting a Manifest Solve My WPF Message Box Style Problems?](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2008/06/08/Will-Setting-a-Manifest-Solve-My-WPF-Message-Box-Style.aspx)
- [The Application Manifest Needed for XP and Vista Style File Dialogs and Message Boxes with WPF](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/The-Application-Manifest-Needed-for-XP-and-Vista-Style-File.aspx)

Fortunately, the open/save dialogs are very thin wrappers around the Win32 API that is easy to call with the right flags to get the Vista/7 style (after setting the manifest)

- [Vista style open and save dialogs with WPF (without using the Vista bridge sample)](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/15/Vista-style-open-and-save-dialogs-with-WPF-without-using.aspx)

Answer (score 18):

Add [The Windows API Code Pack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) to your project

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

...

var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use Windows Forms nor edit manifest files, I came up with a very simple hack using WPF's SaveAs dialog for actually selecting a directory.

No using directive needed, you may simply copy-paste the code below !

It should still be very user-friendly and most people will never notice.

The idea comes from the fact that we can change the title of that dialog, hide files, and work around the resulting filename quite easily.

It is a big hack for sure, but maybe it will do the job just fine for your usage...

In this example I have a textbox object to contain the resulting path, but you may remove the related lines and use a return value if you wish...

```
// Create a "Save As" dialog for selecting a directory (HACK)
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = textbox.Text; // Use current value for initial dir
dialog.Title = "Select a Directory"; // instead of default "Save As"
dialog.Filter = "Directory|*.this.directory"; // Prevents displaying files
dialog.FileName = "select"; // Filename will then be "select.this.directory"
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    string path = dialog.FileName;
    // Remove fake filename from resulting path
    path = path.Replace("\\select.this.directory", "");
    path = path.Replace(".this.directory", "");
    // If user has changed the filename, create the new directory
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    // Our final value is in path
    textbox.Text = path;
}
```

The only issues with this hack are :

- Acknowledge button still says "Save" instead of something like "Select directory", but in a case like mines I "Save" the directory selection so it still works...
- Input field still says "File name" instead of "Directory name", but we can say that a directory is a type of file...
- There is still a "Save as type" dropdown, but its value says "Directory (*.this.directory)", and the user cannot change it for something else, works for me...

Most people won't notice these, although I would definitely prefer using an official WPF way if microsoft would get their heads out of their asses, but until they do, that's my temporary fix.

Comment: underrated answer

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog is the standard dialog that any application on Windows uses.  Your user won't be surprised by its appearance when you use WPF in .NET 4.0

The dialog was altered in Vista.  WPF in .NET 3.0 and 3.5 still used the legacy dialog but that was fixed in .NET 4.0.  I can only guess that you started this thread because you are seeing that old dialog.  Which probably means you're actually running a program that is targeting 3.5.  Yes, the Winforms wrapper *did* get the upgrade and shows the Vista version.  System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog class, you'll need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: I think the point is that the OpenFileDialog cannot be used to select a folder.

Answer (score 5):

MVVM + WinForms FolderBrowserDialog as behavior

```
public class FolderDialogBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public string SetterName { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK && AssociatedObject.DataContext != null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Where(p => p.Name.Equals(SetterName))
            .First();

            propertyInfo.SetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext, dialog.SelectedPath, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
     <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="...">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Behavior:FolderDialogBehavior SetterName="SomeFolderPathPropertyName"/>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     </Button>
```

Blogpost: http://kostylizm.blogspot.ru/2014/03/wpf-mvvm-and-winforms-folder-dialog-how.html

Answer (score 3):

Based on Oyun's answer, it's better to use a dependency property for the FolderName. This allows (for example) binding to sub-properties, which doesn't work in the original. Also, in my adjusted version, the dialog shows selects the initial folder.

Usage in XAML:

```
<Button Content="...">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <Behavior:FolderDialogBehavior FolderName="{Binding FolderPathPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using Button = System.Windows.Controls.Button;

public class FolderDialogBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    #region Attached Behavior wiring
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    #endregion

    #region FolderName Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FolderName =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FolderName",
            typeof(string), typeof(FolderDialogBehavior));

    public static string GetFolderName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(FolderName);
    }

    public static void SetFolderName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FolderName, value);
    }
    #endregion

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var currentPath = GetValue(FolderName) as string;
        dialog.SelectedPath = currentPath;
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SetValue(FolderName, dialog.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Combine this with @TPowers answer and this works great. Also, for the "i" namespace.. `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Answer (score 3):

The [Ookii Dialogs for WPF](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) has a `VistaFolderBrowserDialog` class that provides a complete implementation of a folder browser dialog for WPF.

> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf

[image: Ookii Folder Browser dialog]

There's also a version that works with [Windows Forms](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-winforms).

Comment: This is the only answer that is not a complete kluge.  The reason you write WPF is to get away from Windows Forms.  Using one Windows Forms dialog drags in all kinds of stuff that you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Only such dialog is [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx). Its part of WinForms, but its actually only wrapper around WinAPI standard OS file dialog. And I don't think it is ugly, its actually part of OS, so it looks like OS it is run on.

Other way, there is nothing to help you with. You either need to look for 3rd party implementation, either free (and I don't think there are any good) or paid.

Comment: Thank you!  This is, by far, the best answer.  Very simple to code for either MVVM or standard windows.

Comment: But this does not allow you to pick a folder... the whole point of the question

Answer (score 1):

A comment on the original question from C. Augusto Proiete suggested Ookii dialogs (https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf).  That's what I ended up using in my situation.  Here's how I used it in my app.

```
var dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog()
{
    Description = "Select Folder",
    RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop,
    ShowNewFolderButton = true,
    UseDescriptionForTitle = true
};

var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
    _mySelectedFolder = dialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to say one thing, `WindowsAPICodePack` can not open `CommonOpenFileDialog` on Windows 7 6.1.7600.