# FolderBrowserDialog method not appearing

Tags: c#

I am currently On my MVVM side. I've developed the "OpenFileDialog" side. Now I am trying to do the opposite. Which is "FolderBrowserDialog" side. But Just trying to Initiate it doesn't work.

`FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog()`

"Cannot resolve FolderBrowserDialog  symbol in other words.

May I ask if there's a certain library I have to bring in to fix this?

Comment: Are you using WPF, then? `FolderBrowserDialog` is in `System.Windows.Forms`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922230/707111, though.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx): it's in `System.Windows.Forms`, so you need a reference to that assembly, and you need to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` to the top of your code.

Comment: No library called System.Windows.Forms :s

Answer (score 1):

Add
`System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` class

[Using FolderBrowserDialog in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547320/using-folderbrowserdialog-in-wpf-application)