# Similar alternative to Microsoft.Office.Core.FileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, filedialog

I need a way for users to select a directory with some sort of folder dialog, and I am currently using the Microsoft.Office.Core.FileDialog FileDialogFolderPicker. I need the folder picker that I use to have a search bar for users to type into, and users need to be able to type in a network location (for example they could type in \\SomeComputer) and have all the sub-folders of that network location show up in the file dialog. Basically, it needs to behave as closely as possible to the Windows File Explorer. This Microsoft tool works perfectly, however it comes with an ugly/out of place Microsoft Excel icon in the corner which I can not for the life of me figure out how to change.

My question is, are there other alternatives to this specific folder picker that offer the same range of functionality?

Or alternatively, does anyone know how to (if it is possible) change the Excel icon on the Microsoft Office folder picker?

[This is what I am trying to change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJbl.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to open a File or to save a file? C# has two native Dialog types `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog`

Comment: I am trying to allow the user to choose a folder, not a file. So (as far as I understand) those options would not work. I need something more like the FolderBrowserDialog, but with the option to search for folder destinations

Comment: You can also use WindowsForms [FolderBrowserDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547320/using-folderbrowserdialog-in-wpf-application)

Comment: The WindowsForms FolderBrowserDialog technically works, but it does not support the search function that I am looking for.

Comment: Well it seems you have to implement your own Dialog. There are a lot of 3rd Party-Controls out there also.