# How do I reference an assembly in Visual Studio 2019? WPF on .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a WPF application using `FolderBrowserDialog` and I know I need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. The only problem being is that there are no sources anywhere on how to do that in Visual Studio 2019.

The main differences are in my Solution explorer the place to reference is called `Dependencies` whereas on every single person's VS it's called references? What's up with that? And when I try to add references to the window for it I don't have the assembly tab, here's what I mean:

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: This is what it's supposed to look like],

and this is what I sadly have:

[image: and this is what I sadly have]

I'm very surprised that this is how it is, is there any reason that this is like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919489/2289942 Look here

Comment: Sadly I am having the same issue. Did you end up finding a fix? I need to add a reference to my other part of the project but not working like it does with a normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `WPF Application`, please create a `WPF App (.NET Framework)`

#### Differences

### [image: wpf application]

[image]