# C# - WPF - getting folder browser dialog without using System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I have this **WPF** app and I want to have there function of getting a directory path from the user. I would like to use some folder browser dialog but I **don't** want to implement it from `System.Windows.Forms` or use some huge script inside. Is there some path getting dialog in WPF already implemented?

I have read answers to similar questions here but it was full of System.Windows.Forms..

I haven't found anything like that in the Toolbox and I'm starting with WPF so I could use some help.

Thank you in advance :]

Comment: What's the problem with System.Windows.Forms (used from WPF) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is there no down side to using System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: @HenkHolterman It just feels weird making WPF app so I wont make the Windows Form app and then use stuff from it there :|

Comment: You don't have to make a WinForms app... just borrow a few classes. @Blam: No , not really.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know, I know.. just thought that WPF will have covered the things that are in WinForms. Not to take them from there, but ok. Was just curious if it really isn't there somewhere and I just can't see it.

Comment: @goodfriend You are not alone on this. I always find it weird everytime I have to reference Windows forms to use the dialogs. I dont understand why WPF does not have their own? Plus I never really liked the FolderBrowserDialog to begin with.

Comment: One concrete problem with the WinForms dialog is you can't parent it. We use parenting to enable programmatic dismissal of modal dialogs.

Comment: Have you tried the [Ookii Dialogs for WPF](https://github.com/caioproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf)?

Answer (score 12):

See my answer to [Select folder dialog WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007882/select-folder-dialog-wpf/17712949#17712949). Basically the [Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/windows-presentation-foundation-4-5-cookbook/book) recommends that you use the [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) if you need a folder browser.

Comment: The Windows API Code Packs are available via Nuget [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Shell/) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Core/). This worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

we use [Ookii Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) in our projects. They have the windows-look and feel and the typical options for filtering etc.

Comment: Here's a link to an updated [Ookii Dialogs for WPF](https://github.com/caioproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) targetting .NET 4.5 and [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf/)

Answer (score 3):

There are no standard native WPF dialogs for what you are looking for, simply because the System.Windows.Forms dialogs are nothing more than wrappers to the system ones. So creating a WPF wrapper makes no sense and will only add to the confusion.

Comment: No; what makes no sense is a UI framework which lacks such basic constructs.  No folder browser dialog?  No numeric updown?  Give me a break.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Ookii Dialogs for WPF](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf)** library has a `VistaFolderBrowserDialog` class that provides a complete implementation of a folder browser dialog for WPF.

> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf

[image: Ookii Folder Browser Dialog]

There's also a version compatible with [Windows Forms](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-winforms) apps