# HOW - Detailed Folder Browser - VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I know how to browse folder with dialog. But when I use bellow code:

```
Dim FBrowserDialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
FBrowserDialog.Description = "Get Folder"
FBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
FBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = True
If FBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    'bla bla bla            
End If
```

I get dialog like this:

[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

I don't have any idea how to get like this.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: have you tried the Windows API code pack? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17713001/2012417

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to the [Windows 7 API Code Pack - Shell](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Shell/) using Nuget.

The following code snippet gives the dialog theme you want:

```
Dim dialog As New Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog()    
dialog.IsFolderPicker = True
dialog.ShowDialog()
```