# Win32 - Select Directory Dialog from C/C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How to select an existing folder (or create new) from a native Win32 application?

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922204/open-directory-dialog). It has a good answer for C#/.NET. But I want the same thing for native Win32.

Anybody knows a solution, free code, etc?

**Update:**

I tried the function from the answer. Everything worked as expected, except it is necessary to call the `SHGetPathFromIDList` function to retrieve the name of selected directory. Here is a sample screen shot:

[image: Example of the directory pickup dialog.]

Comment: For more modern code (Windows Vista or later), consider IFileDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[SHBrowseForFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera)

Do your users a favor, and set at least the `BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE` flag.

To set the initial folder, add the following code:

```
static int CALLBACK BrowseFolderCallback(
                  HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{
    if (uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED) {
        LPCTSTR path = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(lpData);
        ::SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, true, (LPARAM) path);
    }
    return 0;
}

// ...
BROWSEINFO binf = { 0 };
...
binf.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(initial_path_as_lpctstr); 
binf.lpfn = BrowseFolderCallback;
...
```

and provide a suitable path (such as remembering the last selection, your applications data folder, or similar)

Comment: Initializing folder works great. Make sure that the path components are using "\\" instead of "/" path separators. I used `::GetFullPathName()` to perform the normalization.

Comment: How to get a string path from the `ITEMIDLIST` returned by the dialog?

Comment: @Victor:    `SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, pathBuffer)` - but see the remarks in msdn for SHBrowseForFolder (e.g. shortcuts will not be resolved)

Answer (score 17):

Just as a go to for future users, this article helped me a lot with getting a directory dialog in C++

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2604/Browse-Folder-dialog-search-folder-and-all-sub-fol

Here is my code (heavily based/taken on the article)

*NOTE: You should be able to copy/paste this into a file / compile it (g++, see VS in ninja edit below) and it'll work.*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

static int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{

    if(uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
    {
        std::string tmp = (const char *) lpData;
        std::cout << "path: " << tmp << std::endl;
        SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, lpData);
    }

    return 0;
}

std::string BrowseFolder(std::string saved_path)
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];

    const char * path_param = saved_path.c_str();

    BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
    bi.lpszTitle  = ("Browse for folder...");
    bi.ulFlags    = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
    bi.lpfn       = BrowseCallbackProc;
    bi.lParam     = (LPARAM) path_param;

    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder ( &bi );

    if ( pidl != 0 )
    {
        //get the name of the folder and put it in path
        SHGetPathFromIDList ( pidl, path );

        //free memory used
        IMalloc * imalloc = 0;
        if ( SUCCEEDED( SHGetMalloc ( &imalloc )) )
        {
            imalloc->Free ( pidl );
            imalloc->Release ( );
        }

        return path;
    }

    return "";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::string path = BrowseFolder(argv[1]);
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've updated the code to show people how to remember the last selected path and use that.

Also, for VS, using Unicode character set. replace this line:

```
const char * path_param = saved_path.c_str();
```

With this:

```
std::wstring wsaved_path(saved_path.begin(),saved_path.end());
const wchar_t * path_param = wsaved_path.c_str();
```

My Test code above is compiled with g++, but doing this fixed it in VS for me.

Comment: Using your code in C, it doesn't handle unicode strings quite well?

Answer (score 10):

For Windows Vista and above, it's best to use [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog) with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option for a proper open dialog rather than this tree dialog. See [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776913(v=vs.85)) on MSDN for more details.