# Wix default folder dialog

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I would like to know if there is a way how to use windows choose folder dialog instead of really bad looking one which is in WIX as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Burn***: You can replace the whole MSI GUI by using WiX's Burn (bootstrapper and more) featuring a custom bootstrapper application. The bootstrapper application can do "anything" in terms of GUI.

Please see these similar questions & answers:

- [WIX Installer with modern look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344035/wix-installer-with-modern-look-and-feel/52349744#52349744)
- [Changing text color to Wix dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815)
- [Removing Default dialogs from MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi/52451051#52451051) (please check all answers)

---

***MSI***: And yes, it should be possible to show the standard Windows directory selection dialog by hooking up a custom action to the MSI dialog's **browse button click event** - which will then invoke the Windows common dialog for folder section. Then you set the directory property from the custom action using either C++ or C# or even scripts I guess. Never tried scripts. [This old C++ project could work with some minor massage](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13088/How-to-Browse-for-a-Folder). Or [maybe the first section here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2604/Browse-Folder-dialog-search-folder-and-all-sub-fol).

I did this many years ago, and as I recall I ran into problems with dialog Z-order. In other words the folder selector dialog showed up underneath the MSI dialogs in some cases. I can't recall what I did to fix it, but I think it involved some dysfunctional send-keys stuff before I concluded that MSI dialogs are fundamentally flawed. I think a smoke test is in order before you waste significant time on it. That is the best advice I can cough up since I haven't tried it in years.

---

***Some Links***:

- [MsiSetExternalUI function](https://serverfault.com/questions/434568/is-there-anyway-to-get-msiexec-to-echo-to-stdout-instead-of-logging-to-a-file/615256#615256)
- [Custom Actions and User Interface](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/standard-libraries/custom-actions-and-user-interface/)
- [Win32 - Select Directory Dialog from C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034943/win32-select-directory-dialog-from-c-c)