# how do I use JNA to access this dialog "select folder"

Tags: java, dialog, jna

I have used JNA library and this small API (JnaFileChooser)
https://github.com/steos/jnafilechooser

```
JnaFileChooser fc = new JnaFileChooser();
fc.addFilter("All Files", "*");
fc.addFilter("Pictures", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if (fc.showDialog(parent)) {
File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
// do something with f
```

}

But how do I use JNA to access this dialg "select folder"

[image]

Comment: Please add your code what are you trying to do.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12034943/13912132

Answer (score 0):

The entire dialogue is controlled on the native side.  The package you are are using is already accessing that dialog and that button.

Tracing through the source code of the `JnaFileChooser` class, this dialogue is part of the [`WindowsFolderBrowser`](https://github.com/steos/jnafilechooser/blob/8cc4f3b776d5d2487bba2cb2738d082b71c183c9/api/src/main/java/jnafilechooser/api/WindowsFolderBrowser.java#L79) class. The dialog appears using the `SHBrowseForFolder()` function combined with `SHGetPathFromIDList`, and returns the `path` when the `Select Folder` button is pressed.

```
final Pointer pidl = Shell32.SHBrowseForFolder(params);
if (pidl != null) 
    // MAX_PATH is 260 on Windows XP x32 so 4kB should
    // be more than big enough
    final Pointer path = new Memory(1024 * 4);
    Shell32.SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidl, path);
    final String filePath = path.getWideString(0);
    final File file = new File(filePath);
    Ole32.CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
    return file;
}
```

The `params` variable passed to this function is of native type `BROWSEINFO` which controls the dialog box.  You can see in the code how a few things have been assigned to it (abbreviated version of code):

```
final Shell32.BrowseInfo params = new Shell32.BrowseInfo();
params.hwndOwner = Native.getWindowPointer(parent);
params.ulFlags = Shell32.BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | Shell32.BIF_USENEWUI;
params.lpszTitle = title;
```

If you want to change anything else about the dialog, you need to use a callback.  One of the elements in `BROWSEINFO` is `BFFCALLBACK lpfn;` where you would define that function, e.g., `params.lpfn =` the defined callback function.

Documentation for [`BFFCALLBACK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb762598(v=vs.85)) indicates you'll use the option to use `SendMessage` to change the OK button text with `BFFM_SETOKTEXT`.