# WPF OpenDirectoryDialog in order to get and set the path of a ListView itemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

I have a `ListView` that contains all images of the .jpg format from a given directory. It's filled by the codebehind using the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + App.putanjaSlika);
FileInfo[] images = folder.GetFiles("*.jpg");
for (int i = 0; i<images.Length; ++i)
{
    FileInfo img = images[i];
    Thumbnails.Items.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(img.FullName)));
}
```

This works marvelously, but as you can see, the path is pretty much set in stone. What I need is some sort of a `BrowseDirectoryDialog` that can allow me to "open" a given directory, and use the located path as the argument for the first line of the above code.

I've found this question [Open directory dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922204/open-directory-dialog) and I like the Ookii.Dialogs solution, but perhaps even more the solution under the second answer. However, seeing as how that thread is 3.5 years old, I wanted to ask if a better solution came out, since I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published this folder browser dialog for WPF in 2011:

http://wpffolderbrowser.codeplex.com/

It is based on an MSDN example and full source code is provided, so you can adapt it as needed. I like it better than the solution mentioned in the linked post, because it displays the "new style" open folder dialog with Vista / Windows 7 look and feel, as opposed to the WinForms dialog which seems to be the same as in Windows 95.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for. Real nice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no dialogs of WPF. So you have to use Winforms.

Comment: This always bugged me as well.  The thought was WPF shouldn't have traditional pop up dialogs (that is a winforms approach).  That being said they should have had some type of embedded control that would do the same thing so you could place it on a popout screen or some type of slider.