# How to Get the Target Folder

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, folderbrowserdialog

I was just at [Open directory dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922204/open-directory-dialog), and they said "get this package, and do this and this to get a folder select window to show up". Well, that all works great, using the Windows API Code Pack-Shell package. However, now I want to get the actual folder that is selected. I didn't notice them mentioning this anywhere.

I tried to do `string folderLocation = Convert.ToString(dialog);` (dialog is the variable for opening the folder window), but that only gave me like the property of the variable. I also tried this: `CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
string folderLocation = Convert.ToString(result);`

But that just gave me "Ok" - which I take it is the result of it, instead of the actual folder.

Comment: If you had read the answers in that question, you would have found the answer to your question. You need to be a little bit persistent with these things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open directory dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922204/open-directory-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of ShowDialog just indicates wether the user clicked OK, cancel, or just closed the window.
`CommonOpenFileDialog` can be used for both files and folders, so it's a bit surprising when used as a folder picker, but the path is stored in `FileName`.

```
var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
if(dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok) {
    Console.WriteLine(dlg.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get Folder for a selected file? If that's the case, you can take FileInfo for that file, and extract folfer from it. Like this:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(oFD1.FileName);
MessageBox.Show(fInfo.DirectoryName);
```

PS. oFD1 is OpenFileDialog