# Is Owner Window required in WPF FolderBrowserDialog in 2021?

Tags: wpf, folderbrowserdialog

When using FolderBrowserDialog in WPF, I've seen a few answers where using the Win32 API is required to make it modal. For example,

[Using FolderBrowserDialog in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547320/using-folderbrowserdialog-in-wpf-application)

[How to use a FolderBrowserDialog from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315164/how-to-use-a-folderbrowserdialog-from-a-wpf-application)

Actually, is the Win32 Api REALLY required ? I just tried the FolderBrowserDialog and it is already modal by default; simply calling .ShowDialog() is already modal to the underlying window. (What are the other answers talking about or have the wpf internals changed ?)

EDIT: using Visual Studio 2015 with .NET framework (not core)

Comment: Why are you still using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @Dai, if it ain't broke, don't fix it ! I am not one to jump on the latest and greatest bs :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, is the Win32 Api REALLY required

Yes. The `FolderBrowserDialog` is exposed through Win32. You can't write software for Windows without using Win32 in some way or another.

> I just tried the FolderBrowserDialog and it is already modal by default; simply calling .ShowDialog() is already modal to the underlying window.

That's because when you call `ShowDialog()` it passes `IntPtr.Zero` for the owner `hWnd` parameter (the same as `NULL` in C). When you pass `NULL` then Windows uses the currently active window in the process as the owner - so an owner is still set, it's just determined automatically:

[From the documentation for WinForms' `ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_) (the overload without the `owner` parameter. While WinForms and WPF are separate, the principle is the same for both):

> When this version is called, **the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box**. If you want to specify a specific owner, use the other version of this method.

That said, you *should* still specify the owner hWnd where possible because you may rearchitect your application and may want a different window to be the owner (e.g. when you want to show a dialog immediately after the non-root parent window closes)

Comment: The other answers in my question seemed to imply we MUST use it, else it won't be modal. For a simple util tool with one main window, i'll leave the fancy owner window stuff out.

Comment: @joedotnot Only one of the answers in the two questions you posted is written in a way that implies you need it. That answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: my bad about the link, but there were others which had me confused, hence the question.